# Calling Web Geoprocessing Services From Other Programs

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing

Where can I go to find information about calling ArcGIS Server geoprocessing services from other programs like a .NET Framework program or possibly even a SQL Server job?

So far, I've found [Using ESRI geoprocessing services from a non-ESRI client (Python)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29410/using-esri-geoprocessing-services-from-a-non-esri-client-python) which seems to indicate that I'll have to put together a program to call the REST interface from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Esri help on that: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_geoprocessing_tasks_in_web_applications/005700000064000000/

You can use the GP service task which is exposed via REST and basically any client that can talk http will be able to submit a job.